# What is the fastest way to create a nan array, with a given size, in F#?

Tags: f#

As the title says, I'm looking for the fastest way to make this:

let MakeNaNArray size : float[] =
    ...

Is there a primitive that would allow to do this?

One option is to fill the array with 0xff bytes, but I'm not sure what is the best method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.create%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) e.g.

```
let arr = Array.create 5 nan
```

Comment: In F# you can actually replace `System.Double.NaN` by just `nan` (also, you can use `infinity` in place of `System.Double.PositiveInfinity` and `-infinity` in place of `System.Double.NegativeInfinity`)